# Cancel call to controller through jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a small login screen. I am not using any API. The way I have set up the login screen is as follow

1. User enters login name and password in VIEW.
2. User clicks login button.
3. I validate user details through AJAX.
4. At this stage, if details are correct, I transfer user to the next page.
5. If details are incorrect I just put in error message.

Here is the JQuery code I got.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var returnType;
        $("#loginButton").click(function () {
            var loginDetails = { 
                loginName: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("VerifyLoginDetails", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(loginDetails),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        if (data.loginAuthentication == 1) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        if (data.loginAuthentication == -2) {
                            $("#password").attr("style", "display:block;");
                            alert("incorrect password");
                            return false;
                        }

                        if (data.loginAuthentication == -1) {
                            $("#username").attr("style", "display:block;");
                            alert("incorrect un");
                            return false;
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

As far as my knowledge is concerned, if I return true, it should not send the call to the controller but, for some reason, it still does. Any suggestions on how can I stop the call to the controller through jQuery?

Comment: Where is next pege call code?

Answer (score 3):

Chances are that `#loginButton` is in a form that is submitted when the button is clicked. You can use `preventDefault()` to stop this behavior:

```
$("#loginButton").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Comment: If that is the case, you probably want to handle the form's `submit` instead of the buttons `click` event

Comment: I tried e.preventDefault(). with this the code behaves cancels the call to controller in every case. I want to cancel it when I return false.

Comment: @AbdulMuneeb: The `true` and `false` you return are returned to jQuery that doesn't care what you return. Instead of returning a value you need to perform the desired action, e.g. navigating the browser to a new page. Note that you probably need some kind of server involvement in setting a authentication cookie based on the login information. Otherwise your authentication will be very easy to circumvent.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the success function does nothing as far as I can see. What you should be doing is placing your redirection code where you have "return true".

To do this use window.location.href.

> window.location.href = "https://google.com";

Comment: Slappy! How can I do so. I am transferring to a different view through controller. How can I do so using JQuery

Comment: Just set window.location.href to the destination url

Comment: You are aware this is happening on the client and not the server? The way the question is formed and the questions you are asking seem to indicate you believe this code executes on the server?

Comment: well I do believe it is executed on client side, this is what I want to achieve. It is working fine now. <br/> Thanks to you slappy and martin. my code is working fine. I am going to post code now.

Comment: Great, what did you change

Comment: I have added e.preventDefault() as suggested by Martin. I am redirecting from client side now.

Comment: I cannot post the code. It says I can post it after 8 house so I will try later but I have mentioned how I sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This Code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var returnType=false;
        $("#loginButton").click(function () {
            var loginDetails = { 
                loginName: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("VerifyLoginDetails", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(loginDetails),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        if (data.loginAuthentication == 1) {
                            returnType=true;
                        }

                        if (data.loginAuthentication == -2) {
                            $("#password").attr("style", "display:block;");
                            alert("incorrect password");
                            returnType=false;
                        }

                        if (data.loginAuthentication == -1) {
                            $("#username").attr("style", "display:block;");
                            alert("incorrect un");
                            returnType=false;
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
            return returnType;
        });
    });
```